# Delete a line from a table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin

i'm currently working on an admin which permit to the user who has the rights to delete any account with a button, and all the accounts are displayed in a table and stored in a database (i'm using MySQL). For each row of the , there is a delete button, and i would like that, by pressing the button of the choosed row, it delete the account of the row selected. I dont really know how to do it clearly that's why I ask.

Can someone explain me the approach that i should take and give me an idea.
Have a good day.
[the admin pannel screen][1]

Here is where I am in my code :

```
<?php 

require_once('testadmin.php');

if(!$isAdmin) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

include_once('./includes/head.php');
include_once('./includes/nav.php'); 

require_once('./lib/db.php');

// users
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<main>
    <table id="usersTable">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;margin-top: 25px;">Users</h1>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
    
    <?php 
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        echo 
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$user['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['username'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['email'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['role'].'</td>
            <td><button class="btn-danger" onclick=\'return confirm("Confirm account delete?");\'>
            <a href="delete.php" class="delete" style="color: #fff">Delete account</a></button></td></tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

delete.php :
NOTE : this is actually for delete the current connected account.

```php
<?php
require('./lib/db.php');
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
}

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$req = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:id');
$req->bindValue(':id', $user["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->execute();

unset($_SESSION['user']);
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Please do not deface your post with a useless edit.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the identifier for the record to the `delete.php` page:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=' . $user['id'] . '" class="delete" style="color: #fff">
```

Then in `delete.php` you can reference `$_GET['id']` and use that value in your SQL query to delete that specific record.

---

Note of course that within `delete.php` you'll probably want to make sure the current user is *authorized* to delete that record.

Comment: @ishhh: It's not clear what you mean by that.  Can you elaborate on that problem, and how it relates to the specific question being asked above?  If there's some other unrelated problem, you may consider opening a new question.

Comment: @ishhh: So then in `delete.php` instead of `$user["id"]` you'd use `$_GET['id']` to delete the *specified* user instead of the *current* user, exactly as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @ishhh: What?  Why?  Are you *trying* to make a `<form>` instead of just a link?  The question makes no mention of that.  What exactly isn't working here?